# i get error file name not defined during python file operation.how to define it before for statement

Tags: python

executed python file "test.py".....getting below error.how to define file name? My intention to see the content of file in reverse order.

### test.py content

```
for line in reversed(list(open(testing.txt))):
      print(line.rstrip())
```

## error

```
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    filename = testing.txt
NameError: name 'testing' is not defined
```

Comment: Filenames are strings -> `'testing.txt'` not `testing.txt`

Comment: I can't resist: this is why Python is hateable. A real language would fail on the compile step instead of forcing you to run it first.

Comment: @nicomp And how is that any better?

Comment: Thanks G. Anderson. Agree with nicomp as iam a beginner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `testing.txt` to `"testing.txt"`. Filenames in Python are strings.

Comment: Explain why. Expand your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open a file in Python, you have to use

```
open("filename.txt")
```

instead of

```
open(filename.txt)
```

This is to tell the Python interpreter that you refer to a string, but not to a variable. In Python, strings are the normal representation of text.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `with` statement to open a file will close the file even if an **error** occurs.
The `with` statement creates a `context manager` and it will automatically close the file handler for you when you are done with it.

```
with open("testing.txt", 'r') as myfile:  # opens the file in read mode
  data = myfile.readlines()  # read the file content

print("".join(list(reversed(data))))  # print the file content from bottom to top
```